# Trying to make std::make_pair take more than 2 arguments

Tags: c++

I was previously returning 2 items in my return statement, but  i had to modify it so that i could return 3 things, I have made some changes to the code, this is what looks like

```
std::pair<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> get(InputValidator inputValidator){
    std::string imageURL = inputValidator.url();

    Requests requests;
    cv::Mat image = requests.downloadImageFromURL(imageURL);
    if(image.empty())
        return std::make_pair(0,empty, "");

    try{
        std::vector<std::string> elements;
        cv::Mat croppedFI = rotated_f(image);
        std::string returnFP = rotated_F(image);
        elements.push_back(returnFP);
        std::string uploadUrl = requests.uploadImageToURL(APP.uploadURLSilo, cropped);
        elements.push_back(uploadUrl);
        // return elements[0], elements[1];
        return std::make_pair(0, uploadUrl,returnFP);
```

but this throws an error like

```
app.cpp: In member function ‘std::pair<int,std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > ResponseFunction::get(InputValidator)’:
app.cpp:91:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(int, std::__cxx11::string&, const char [1])’
             return std::make_pair(0,empty, "");
```

The traceback continues but mostly looks like the same error.

My c++ is not that great ,any ideas would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `std::tuple`?

Comment: Hmmm, i havent checked it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could fix the error by writing

```
return std::make_pair(0, std::make_pair(uploadUrl,returnFacePoints));
```

But `std::pair`, as the name suggests, is not made for holding three things. `std::tuple` exists for combining any number of things:

```
return std::make_tuple(0, uploadUrl, returnFacePoints);
```

The return type of the function would just be

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, std::string> get(InputValidator inputValidator){
```

Do note that this is not exactly best practice in C++. A user of your function has no idea that the first returned `std::string` is the upload URL and the other one is about the face points - and even if they know, it's very easy to confuse the two. Yes, other languages do this too, but they tend to have smaller code bases.

Comment: ...so what do you suggest instead? I guess writing a struct with three properly named members, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time , i am implementing this at the moment

Comment: @user463035818 There are several alternatives. The most straightforward would be a struct indeed - at least in terms of clarity. I dislike the associated maintenance overhead though (assuming this function is not part of your public API and is subject to changes). Refactoring tools generally have no idea what you want from them if any part needs to be changed. There are return parameters (which the tools _do_ understand) but those have similar issues regarding clarity as `std:tuple`. Then there's classes/OOP with its own can of worms. Pick your poison.

Comment: one question ,can i call some_variable.first , .second ,.third on std::tuple?

Comment: using `std::tuple` is okay, in c++17 you can use structure binding so it's quite convenient

Comment: @Ryan No. If your C++ version is new enough (C++17 and up), you can use structured bindings to split the returned value into multiple variables: `auto [myInt, uploadUrlToUse, returnedFacePoints] = get(myInputValidator);` (that declares and initializes those three new variables). Before C++17 you have to declare those variables beforehand and use `std::tie`. There's no `std::triplet` or similar, to preempt that question.

Comment: Oh, Then its a problem for me , Anyways in your first method using std::make_pair, how do i call .first .second etc, because i tried calling my_variable.third  and it threw an error saying has no member named third,\

Comment: @Ryan You can use [std::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) for that.

Comment: @Ryan If your return value is in `ret`, then `ret.first` is an `int` and `ret.second` is the `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, so you need `ret.second.first` and `ret.second.second`. The pairs nest. But note how ugly and unreadable that gets.

Comment: Oh, okay ,Thanks , let me try this

Comment: @Ryan Yes, except instead of `some_variable.first`, `some_variable.second` and `some_variable.third`, it's `std::get<N>(some_variable)`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I just got done implementing this, Thanks a lot for the help, I know this is  a bit ugly and unreadable but i think this will have to do for now.Thanks again .